# Using python with windows command prompt

Tags: python, cmd

An integral part of Tensorflow guides are windows shell commands that control python. Unfortunately I do not know how to use it correctly, resulting in me not being able to proceed in the Tensorflow guide. Is there a guide on how to use snippets like:

[image]

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/image_recognition

Comment: Provide what the problem/error is, the commands look perfectly fine, for windows you need to change the **/** to **\\** for windows commands.

Comment: what version of python are you using? try 'python3 classify_image.py' instead of 'python classify_image.py'

Comment: Python 3, how would I enter this command/commands? it doesnt work

Comment: "Through a keyboard". You are kind of stingy with the details of what you exactly are having problems with. Do you have a keyboard?

Comment: oh hit the windows key, type 'cmd' to open command prompt, then use 'cd' to get to the imagnet folder, then type the python command to execute the python file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open up your terminal by Pressing `Windows+R` on your Keyboard, then typing in `cmd` and then pressing enter.

Then type in the commands, press enter and they should get executed.

Was this you question?

Answer (score 0):

cd changes directories, so it's just changing the current directory you're in.  Those commands change directories to the "imagenet" folder then runs python on an included program.